# Add values for dictionary with same key and value pair

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I want to merge the list of dictionaries based on same key value pair. I have a list of dictionaries as

```
[{'id':1, 'total':100,'free_from':250},{'id':2,....},{'id':1,......}]
```

I want to make a new list of dictionaries from this with same structure but if the id is same for two dictionaries their total should get added instead of adding dictionary to new list.

This is the list of dictionary

```
products = [{'id':1,'total':20,'free_from':250,},{'id':2,'total':30,'free_from':150},{'id':1,'total':10,'free_from':250,},{'id':1,'total':10,'free_from':250},{'id':2,'total':40,'free_from':150, }]
```

and expected result is

```
[{ 'id': 1,'total': 40, 'free_from': 250}, {'id': 2,'total': 70, 'free_from': 150}]
```

I managed to achieve this by using following method. But it would be great help if someone can help me in finding a better way to do this.

```
category_delivery_list=[]
products = [
    {
        'id':1,
        'total':20,
        'free_from':250,
    },{
        'id':2,
        'total':30,
        'free_from':150, 
    },{
        'id':1,
        'total':10,
        'free_from':250, 
    },{
        'id':1,
        'total':10,
        'free_from':250, 
    },{
        'id':2,
        'total':40,
        'free_from':150, 
    }
]
for data in products:
    if category_delivery_list:
        index = None
        for count, cat in enumerate(category_delivery_list):
            if cat['id'] == data['id']:
                index=count
        if index >= 0:
            category_delivery_list[index]['total'] += data['total']
            category_delivery_list[index]['free_from'] = data['free_from']
        else:
            category_delivery_list.append({
                'id':data['id'],
                'total':data['total'],
                'free_from':data['free_from']
            })
    else:
        category_delivery_list.append({
            'id':data['id'],
            'total':data['total'],
            'free_from':data['free_from']
        })
print(category_delivery_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way of doing this is via a temporary dictionary:

```
temp = {}
for data in products:
    if data["id"] in temp:
        temp[data["id"]]["total"] += data["total"]
        temp[data["id"]]["free_from"] += data["free_from"]
    else:
        temp[data["id"]] = data.copy()
category_delivery_list = list(temp.values)
```

This creates a temp dictionary `id` -> `{'id':.., 'total':..., 'free_from':...}` and then iterates over the list and adds a new entry or adds to an existing entry.